# Wireshark overhead while sniffing WPA decrypted packet

Tags: wireshark, wpa

As the title says, while sniffing WPA protected packet in my WiFi network using Wireshark, if I decrypt them with Wireshark tool, I can analyze them, but I found that there are always 12 byte of overhead that lack in the crypted packet and haven't any tag in Wireshark menu. Thanks

Comment: sorry is there a question here somewhere?

Comment: I do not understand what those 12 bytes are....because this bytes are present only in the decrypted packet but aren't present in the same crypted packet

Answer (score 1):

if you are saying the decrypted packed is smaller than the encrypted packed that is probably [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7)... which is added to make a whole block so it can perform whole block operations on the cipher and be used as a sanity check on decrypt... ie. assume 16 byte blocksize (aes) if you have a payload that is `len(payload) % 16 = 4` then you will need to add 12 bytes of padding...

in PKCS7 padding you would add the octet `0x0c` 12 times before you encrypt it, and strip the padding when you decrypt it.

Comment: but my problem is right the opposite. i mean that the encrypted packet has  12 bytes less than the decrypted packet

Comment: @GiulianoFagiani I think you will have to give us an example, hex of each and a key, if you can do it in a way that doesn't compromise your security.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I solved my problem because the 12 bytes are due to the TKIP algorithm.